# Firebase Functions Reference Error

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

i'm using firebase functions to initiate a notification push to each user.  The function looks like:

```
  'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require ('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{recieverid}/{notificationid}')
    .onWrite((data,context) =>
    {
        console.log(data);
    const recieverid = context.params.recieverid;
    const notificationid = context.params.notificationid;


    const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/users/${recieverid}/token`).value;

    return deviceToken.then(result=> 
    {
        const token = result.val();
        const payload = 
        {
            notification: 
            {
                title: "You've been caught!",
                body: "Somebody likes you as much as you like them",
                icon:"default"
            }
        };
      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload);

    });
});
```

and i'm receiving the following error though the logs:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:17:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
    at next (native)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
    at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:728:24
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

any ideas on why i'm getting the above error and more importantly how to fix it? new to JS but not to Java.

James

Comment: You seem to have missed some of the steps in the migration guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#sdk_changes_that_affect_all_background_non_http_functions

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js process, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Answer (score 1):

```
const reciever_id = event.params.reciever_id;
const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;
console.log('We have a notification to send to: ', reciever_id);

if(!event.data.val());
```

Error is because no variable named `event` is declared. Maybe you are to use `data` or `context` instead of `event` as the function returns them `onWrite`?

Comment: so i changed it so that instead of (data,context) it reads event and i'm now getting a "TypeError: Cannont read property 'recieverid' .....?  how would i get the reciverid if i left it as (data,context)?

Comment: can you log `event` object? The error states that `event.param` is undefined. Log what is getting returned in `onWrite` function and see if you are accessing the properties like `recieverid` correctly.

Comment: nope i just keep getting the Type error in the log?

Comment: `.onWrite((event, data, context)=>{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event), JSON.stringify(data), JSON.stringify(context));
}`

Comment: So i'm getting some info come up which shows a DataSnapshot before and after? is that what you're looking for?

Comment: use the json from logs to find the property `recieverid`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176680/discussion-between-sushim-mukul-dutta-and-james-palfrey).

Comment: back online now if you want to talk though it

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, code below:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database
.ref('/notifications/{recieverid}/{notificationid}')
.onWrite((snapshot,context) => {
    console.log(snapshot);
    const recieverid = context.params.recieverid;
    const notificationid = context.params.notificationid;

    return admin.database().ref(`/users/${recieverid}/token`).once('value', function(snapshot) {
        const token = snapshot.val();
        const payload = 
        {
            notification: 
            {
                title: "SomeTitle",
                body: "SomeBody",
                icon: "default"
            }
        };
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload).then(function(response){
            return console.log("Successfully sent message:", response)
        });
    });
});
```